# How to place bootstrap button on right corner without breaking hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a connect button on the top right corner of the screen on mobile and desktop before the hamburger menu. However all solutions I tried break the menu.

- putting the connect button and hamburger button after menu break the toggle on mobile
- putting the connect button after the collapsible menu work on desktop but break the layout on mobile

Is there a clean way to do this without resorting to using two button?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light px-3">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Name on Chain</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  ms-auto me-2" id="connectWallet">Connect Wallet</button>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Guide</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Curio I think you can use [JavaScript HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) to change the style of an html element within defined condition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.5.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap-4.5.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light px-3">
        <div id="custom">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="float: left;">Name on Chain</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                style="float:right;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  ms-auto me-0" id="connectWallet" style="float:right;">Connect
                Wallet</button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Guide</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
<style>
    .topright {
        position: fixed;
        width: 135px;
        top: 10px;
    }

    .custom {
        width: 100%
    }
</style>
<script>
    if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
        $('#connectWallet').addClass('topright');
        document.getElementById('connectWallet').style.left = "85%";
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 766) {
        $('#connectWallet').addClass('topright');
        document.getElementById('connectWallet').style.left = "80%";
    } else {
        $('#connectWallet').removeClass('topright');
        $('#custom').addClass('custom');
        document.getElementById('connectWallet').style.left = "0";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I hope this will help solve your problem.

Comment: Check my code you do not need JS for this :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code this will help you.**

Wrap you `toggle button` and `Connect button` in a  `inline-form` just like done in code give below or use `flexbox.`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light px-3">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Name on Chain</a>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Connect Wallet </button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </form>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">



        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Guide</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>


    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Let me know this will help you.**

Comment: This loses the collapse animation effect of hamburger menu.